# While executing the following snippet. I could see an error Global symbol "$colors" requires explicit package name. Key and value has to be printed

Tags: perl

Trying to print fruits followed by their colors using a for loop.

```
use strict; 
my %colors = (  apple      => 'red',
                orange     => 'orange',
                watermelon => 'green',
                grapes     => 'blue',
                rest       => 'pink' );
for (keys %colors) {    
   print("color of  $_  is   $colors($_)\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$colors($_)` must be `$colors{$_}`

Accessing hash values requires the use of `{ }`